# Join in local scope

Tags: laravel, join, scope

I am doing a local scope on my model. Within my scope I am joining to table, but then on my result set I am losing my reference to my relationships.

In Entry model I have
this relationship:

```
  public function items() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Accounting\EntryItem', 'entry_id');
}
```

and this scope:

```
public function scopeWithConst($query, $const_code) {
    return $query->join('consts', function($join) use($const_code) {
                $join->on('consts.code', '=', $const_code);
            });
}
```

In controller:

```
 $entry = Entry::with('items')->withConst('entries.status')->find($id);
```

It always returns "items": [] because of calling "withConst" scope!

Any explanation?

Comment: I suggest installing a debugbar so you can actually see what your query is doing and perform it manually so you can see the results and adjust if needed. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: @Stephan-v Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to replace 'entries.status' with the value of the 'entries.status' of this particular $id in the Entry you are looking for. You could do that with a closure or by finding the value before calling 'withConst'.

```
$status = Entry::find($id)->pluck('status');
$entry = Entry::with('items')->withConst($status)->find($id);
```

or

```
$entry = Entry::with('items')->withConst(function() use ($id) {
    return Entry::find($id)->pluck('status');
    }
  )->find($id);
```

Scopes are reusable restraints, as far as I know, not designed for joins where 2 tables are involved. Depending on how much you need the scope, keep it in the conventional way without a scope.

Comment: Join can't be made on status value.. I should pass the column name "entries.status", but I think as you said scopes are not designed for joins..

Comment: Agreed @MzayanAwad as some questions start with an impossible assumption. This is 99% sure one of them. I'll let it be for a month or so, check public interest, and probably will delete the question all together after that.